How to sort balance in table ascending and descending?
I was try sort the balance in table an ascending and an descending, but can't. I looked the w3schools tutorial and theme in stackoverflow about insertBefore and insertAfter without libraries. But isn't works.
My code:
function sortTableByBalance() {
  let table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;

  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;

    for (i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;

      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[2];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[2];

      if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      } else if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
      else if (!shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i].nextSibling);
       switching = true;
     }
  }
}


Why is there code in comments? What is the HTML?

edited.
html created with js. can show you

Are you actually using the jquery table sorter plug in that you have tagged the question with?

Re-arranging a table in the DOM is dead slow. I'd suggest you to keep data in a JS array, sort data and re-create the table in DocumentFragment, and then replace the current table in the DOM.

really, i tryed to create my personality insertAfter function and i was mean my function, not jquery table sorter plug. sorry. Edited

if simply - create the re render?

The reason your table doesn't get sorted is that you break out of the loop when a pair of balances is not equal. Apparently you wanted to implement some sort of bubble sort, but by exiting the inner loop when you set shouldSwitch to false, that algorithm is not correctly implemented: it will not detect that a next pair is not in the correct order.
So the quick fix is to change this:
  } else if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
    shouldSwitch = false;
    break;

to this:
  } else if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
    shouldSwitch = false;

Better approach
However, you should not have to implement a sort algorithm explicitly. There is sort and you can rely on it for this table sorting as well:
function sortTableByBalance() {
    const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    const arr = Array.from(table.rows, row => [row, +row.cells[2].textContent]).slice(1);
    arr.sort(([,a], [,b]) => a - b);
    for (const [elem] of arr) {
        table.appendChild(elem);
    }
}


Interesting, but when i try to Array.from I get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')" I think it's because i have an extra line like total balance. Below I will show you what it looks like

no, i removed the total balance from Array.from with slice(1, -1), but textContent & innerHTML Error is still there

That error means your table has a row without a cell in the third column.

I realized why js is complaining, but I don't know how to fix it
It cusses on an empty cell in a column, because I delete all unnecessary rows with slice already after outputting the textContent cells of those rows.

You have not supplied any HTML in your question, so it seems out of scope. If you have a new question, then I suggest you post it as a new question, providing the problematic HTML and what you expect to happen when a row lacks a cell by which you wanted to sort (like: should it be deleted, should it be moved to the very end of the table, the very top, ...etc). I'll be happy to look at it if you post it.
